# How do I call a templated member function without knowing whether or not the class is a template?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Suppose I have the following macro:

```
#define CALL_FOO(x) x.foo<int>();
```

This macro will call the templated `foo` function with template argument `int`, and it will compile as long as `x` is itself not a template type. If it is, I would need to define a second variant of this macro to handle template types:

```
#define CALL_FOO_TEMPLATED(x) x.template foo<int>();
```

How can I create a macro that will call a template member function `foo` regardless of whether or not `x` is a dependent name?

Comment: Can you post an MVCE? [This example](http://ideone.com/0PTFtQ) runs for me - perhaps I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: @chrisb2244, I think [this code](http://ideone.com/4qtUOb) demonstrates the OP's question. Sometimes `template` is required, sometimes it's optional.

Comment: @chrisb2244 I had one but now I can't reproduce it. I suspect it might have been a compiler bug in the specific version I had (can't find it now) because it looks like the provided answers work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer you're looking for, in [temp.names], `template` is required when:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression* or after a
>   *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent
>   or the *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.

but while there are restrictions on the name referred to:

> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be a *template-id* or the name shall refer to a class template.

there are not any restrictions on the "dependence-ness" of it:

> *[ Note:* As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is
>   not strictly necessary; i.e., when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not
>   dependent on a template-parameter, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template. *—end note]*

So the following will always compile fine:

```
struct X
{
    template <typename >
    void foo() { }
};

int main()
{
    X{}.template foo<int >(); // template keyword not strictly necessary
}
```

The **real** answer though is: don't use a macro for such a thing. Just write out the function call. Everybody will thank you later. With the added bonus that at the call site, you know whether or not the `template` keyword is required, so you can use it precisely where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

(First, *never* put a `;` at the end of a macro. It will break inside certain `if` calls.)

I think you can safely put `template` in front of `foo` at all times. Sometimes it is required. Sometimes it's optional. But I don't think it is ever disallowed to have `template` immediately in front of a template.

```
#define CALL_FOO(x) x.template foo<int>()
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++11 just use `template` unconditionally.  For C++03, most compilers will accept `template` even for non-dependent names, but may issue a warning.  If you need to cater to other compilers, or if the warning is not acceptable, you can try something like this:

```
template<class X>
void CALL_FOO(X& x)
{
  x.template foo<int>();
}
template<class X>
void CALL_FOO(const X& x)
{
  x.template foo<int>();
}
```

This does not allow you to pass along the value returned by `foo`.  This is easy enough to add if it is a fixed type.  Otherwise you need some form of `decltype`, which is not part of C++03, but you can try [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/typeof.html).

Comment: FYI, you the `const` overload is redundant. The `X& x` overload can bind to const arguments too.

Comment: @Barry but `X&` can't bind to rvalues, which `const X&` can.

Comment: If we want to support rvalues too, then that's still just one overload, but `X&& x` instead.

Comment: Ah, but these two functions are for the C++03 case.  For C++11 you can just write `template` unconditionally, as I said (and you said that too, in your answer).